# How to select columns from a table which have non null values?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, null

I have a table containing hundreds of columns many of which are null, and I would like have my select statement so that only those columns containing a value are returned. It would help me analyze data better. Something like:

Select (non null columns) from tablename;

I want to select all columns which have at least one non-null value.

Can this be done?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.  As written, it looks like you're asking to SELECT *all* rows from a table?  Is that actually what you're after?  Or do you mean to include a WHERE clause and SELECT only the rows which contain non-NULL values in the columns of interest?  Or do you want to select all columns which are not-nullable for all rows?  Could you please explicate?

Comment: I find the question quite clear. He wants to select only the columns for which at least one row contains data. Having a WHERE clause would make this even more difficult, of course.

Comment: what would you like to do with the data? where is it going to be used?

Comment: "non null" has a quite different meaning to "not nullable". Which do you want - to see rows for which at least one non-null value exists, or to only see the columns which have a "not nullable" constraint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look as statistics information, it may be useful for you:

```
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCOTT','EMP');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select num_rows from all_tables where owner='SCOTT' and table_name='EMP';

  NUM_ROWS
----------
        14

SQL> select column_name,nullable,num_distinct,num_nulls from all_tab_columns
  2  where owner='SCOTT' and table_name='EMP' order by column_id;

COLUMN_NAME                    N NUM_DISTINCT  NUM_NULLS
------------------------------ - ------------ ----------
EMPNO                          N           14          0
ENAME                          Y           14          0
JOB                            Y            5          0
MGR                            Y            6          1
HIREDATE                       Y           13          0
SAL                            Y           12          0
COMM                           Y            4         10
DEPTNO                         Y            3          0

8 rows selected.
```

For example you can check if NUM_NULLS = NUM_ROWS to identify "empty" columns.
Reference: [ALL_TAB_COLUMNS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm#I1020277), [ALL_TABLES](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2105.htm#i1592091).

Comment: thank you brother, there is a problem with large table data is that exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCOTT','EMP'); 
take alot of time.

Answer (score 8):

Use the below:

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'Table_Name' and is_nullable = 'NO'
```

`Table_Name` has to be replaced accordingly...

Comment: Just because a column is nullable, doesn't mean that it won't have data in it.

Comment: Worth noting that `information_schema` is available in MySQL, but not Oracle database. The question is specific to Oracle database. This may help people who are looking for answers related to MySQL, but it's not particularly relevant to the question.

Answer (score 6):

```
select column_name
from user_tab_columns
where table_name='Table_name' and num_nulls=0;
```

Here is simple code to get non null columns..

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this can be done in a single query. You may need some plsql to first test what columns contain data and put together a statement based on that information. Of course, if the data in your table changes you have to recreate the statement.

```
declare

   l_table          varchar2(30) := 'YOUR_TABLE';
   l_statement      varchar2(32767);
   l_test_statement varchar2(32767);

   l_contains_value pls_integer;

   -- select column_names from your table
   cursor c is
      select column_name
            ,nullable
        from user_tab_columns
       where table_name = l_table;

begin
   l_statement := 'select ';
   for r in c
   loop
      -- If column is not nullable it will always contain a value
      if r.nullable = 'N'
      then
         -- add column to select list.
         l_statement := l_statement || r.column_name || ',';
      else
         -- check if there is a row that has a value for this column
         begin
            l_test_statement := 'select 1 from dual where exists (select 1 from ' || l_table || ' where ' ||
                                r.column_name || ' is not null)';
            dbms_output.put_line(l_test_statement);
            execute immediate l_test_statement
               into l_contains_value;


            -- Yes, add column to select list
            l_statement := l_statement || r.column_name || ',';
         exception
            when no_data_found then
               null;
         end;

      end if;
   end loop;

   -- create a select statement
   l_statement := substr(l_statement, 1, length(l_statement) - 1) || ' from ' || l_table;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, column_name || ',')).extract ('//text()'), ',') col
from (select column_name
from user_tab_columns
where table_name='<table_name>' and low_value is not null)
```

Comment: Please don't just write code as an answer. Explain what it does and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This block determines all columns in the table, loops through them in dynamic SQL and checks if they are null, then constructs a DBMS output query of the non-null query.

All you have to do is run the returned query.

I've included the exclusion of PKs and BLOB columns.
Obviously, this is quite slow as going through columns one by one, and it's not going to be great for very hot tables, as data may change too quickly, but this works for me as I control traffic in dev env.

```
DECLARE
  l_table_name      VARCHAR2(255) := 'XXXX';
  l_counter         NUMBER;
  l_sql             CLOB;

BEGIN
  FOR r_col IN (SELECT * 
                FROM user_tab_columns tab_col
                WHERE table_name = l_table_name
                AND data_type NOT IN ('BLOB')
                AND column_name NOT IN (SELECT column_name 
                                        FROM user_cons_columns con_col
                                        JOIN user_constraints cons ON con_col.constraint_name = cons.constraint_name AND con_col.table_name = cons.table_name
                                        WHERE con_col.table_name = tab_col.table_name
                                        AND constraint_type = 'P')
                ORDER BY column_id) 
  LOOP

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(1) FROM '||l_table_name||' WHERE '||r_col.column_name||' IS NOT NULL'
    INTO l_counter;
    
    IF l_counter > 0 THEN
      IF  l_sql IS NULL THEN 
        l_sql := r_col.column_name;
      ELSE   
        l_sql :=  l_sql||','||r_col.column_name;
      END IF;
    END IF;
   
  END LOOP;  

  l_sql :=  'SELECT '||l_sql||CHR(10)
         ||'FROM '||l_table_name;
          
  ----------
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_sql);  
END;
```

Answer (score -2):

What you're asking to do is establish a dependency on each row in the whole result. This is in fact *not ever* what you want. Just think of the ramifications if in one row every column had a value of '0' -- suddenly the schema of your result set grows to include all of those previously "empty" columns. You're effectively growing the badness of '*' exponentially, now your result set is not dependent on just the table's meta-data -- but your whole result set is dependent on the plain data.

What you want to do is just select the fields that have what you want, and not deviate from this simple plan.

Comment: I'm thinking they just want to see the relevant camouflaged data amidst the sea of hundreds of columns of NULLs everywhere.  That will help them to ultimately build a query with specific fields.