# Mysql select only column has data

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I would like to select only columns that has only data in mysql.

In example, i have table1 as the follwing:

```
Table1

NAME VAL1 VAL2 VAL3 VAL4
A   1     2
B   2     3
C   3     3
```

select name,val1,val2,val3,val4 from Table1;

How can i select only Name,val1,val2 in mysql  ?

```
Result:

    Table1

    NAME VAL1 VAL2 
    A    1     2
    B    2     3
    C    3     3
```

Regards

Comment: select name, val1, val2 from table1?

Comment: no i want to select all but not include null column

Comment: How can ? can u tell me ?

Comment: What do you expect if only a single row has a NULL value in one of the columns? e.g. NAME = 'A' with a VAL2 = null?

Comment: Duplicate of this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219870/how-to-select-columns-from-a-table-which-have-non-null-values

Comment: @Vivek PL/SQL from Oracle offers way more ways to solve this than MySQL

Answer (score 2):

You HAVE to deal with `null` values and what you trying to achieve is NOT possible. Because you can't predict how many columns won't be `NULL` **before** executing the statement.

There are many easy ways in PHP or other languages tho, sorting out your results to fit your needs.

Comment: you just ignore them.. `if (is_null($result['val1']))` in PHP, or `IFNULL(val1, 'val1 is null');` in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

you can just select those two columns like that

```
   SELECT name, CONCAT_WS(',',VAL1,val2,val3,val4) as vals FROM `table1`
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23e91/9)

and then separate them in php

Comment: he wants `val3` too, but only if it has no rows containing `null`. And he doesn't want `val2` if 1 row has `null` values. There is no plain MySQL answer containing 'it is possible'

Comment: yes,DanFromGermany  correct u said right. i select all but not include null column.

Comment: Your question is very good, but the answer is simply that you can't do it. You need to find a different way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively not possible as you want to return a different number of columns on each row which MySQL is not set up to do. As such it is a presentation issue.

Beyond that you could return all the non null fields grouped into a single record.

```
SELECT NAME, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(' - ', 
IF(VAL1 IS NULL, NULL, CONCAT('VAL1=', VAL1)), 
IF(VAL2 IS NULL, NULL, CONCAT('VAL2=', VAL2)), 
IF(VAL3 IS NULL, NULL, CONCAT('VAL3=', VAL3)), 
IF(VAL4 IS NULL, NULL, CONCAT('VAL4=', VAL4))))
FROM Table1
```

Quite horrible to use though.