# SQL - get only colums from a table where not all values are nulls

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL question:
How do I get all column values from columns where not all values are null?

Table A

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4    COL5
---------------------------------------
abc     1       NULL    NULL    NULL
def     2       NULL    testA   NULL
NULL    3       NULL    testB   NULL
jkl     4       NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I want to get

```
COL1    COL2    COL4    
-----------------------
abc     1       NULL    
def     2       testA   
NULL    3       testB   
jkl     4       NULL
```

Is there a sql or plsql solution achieve this this?
To avoid answers that are irrelevant: assume I have a million rows.
I want the result to be a view or a result table.
Not a written output.

I found a similar question, but it does not satisfy my need:
[How to select columns from a table which have non null values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219870/how-to-select-columns-from-a-table-which-have-non-null-values)

The column names can be quickly grabbed through this query

```
select column_name 
from all_tab_columns 
where lower(table_name)='tableA' and num_distinct > 0;
```

I understand I could create a script with a cursor and then loop through it, adding the result to a new table or view.
This is not what I need. I wondered if this could be done using a single query, using pivot/unpivot or something else.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question. I removed the database tags as it is unclear which one you are actually using. Please add the tag of *only* the database you are actually using

Comment: So you want different number of columns depending on table data? Well, SQL doesn't work like that, the result set columns are defined at compile time, before any data is read.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible in plain SQL, unless you know ahead of time which columns only have NULL everywhere. (It seems that you don't want to assume that you know that.)

Which columns are included in the output - how many columns, their names, and in what order they appear - must be hard-coded in the `SELECT` clause, it can't be determined at runtime. On the other hand, you will only know which columns are all-NULL only after reading the data (meaning, at runtime) - or else you must have that information from an external source.

The only way to do what you seem to want to do is with **dynamic SQL**. That is an advanced topic, and a technique generally considered a poor business practice.

WHY do you not want to show columns with all-NULL values? Are you sure that requirement is meaningful?

Comment: As to the why:Imagine a legacy database of 7000 tables, some of them unnormalized. The lack of the database model on certain areas forces us to reverse engineer how they were set up. To get only the relevant data on a visible screen, would assist us in getting this overview faster.

We would not use this queries in production nor within the applications, but we wanted to deliver these as tools to our support crew.

Answer (score 1):

try these steps, it may help:

```
Create table temp as (Select * from TableA)

Declare NbrRows Number(10);
plsql_block VARCHAR2(1000);
CountNullRows Number (10)

Select count(*) as nbr 
into NbrRows
from TableA

Select count(COL1) as nbr
into CountNullRows
from TableA where COL1 is null

if (NbrRows = CountNullRows) then
Alter table Temp drop column COL1
endif

Select count(COL2) as nbr
into CountNullRows
from TableA where COL2 is null

if (NbrRows = CountNullRows) then
Alter table Temp drop column COL2
endif

Select count(COL3) as nbr
into CountNullRows
from TableA where COL3 is null

if (NbrRows = CountNullRows) then
Alter table Temp drop column COL3
endif

...etc...
```

Do the same thing for all your columns

You have the desired result in the Tem table.